# $[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n,(1+\frac{1}{n})^{(n+1)}]$ are nested

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show that intervals $[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n,(1+\frac{1}{n})^{(n+1)}]$ are nested. It is clear that:

$$ (1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1+\frac{1}{n})^{(n+1)} < 0,   \forall n \in \mathbb N$$

and

$$ (1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1+\frac{1}{n})^{(n+1)} \to 0  $$.

What I am stuck with is to show that $$\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{(n+1)}}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n} > 1$$ and $$\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{(n+2)}}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}} < 1$$.

So I have tried with Bernoulli's inequality and $\frac{1}{1+x} \le \log(x+1) \le x$.

Comment: Consider "smoothing" the problem out by looking at functions such as $f(x) = x \log(1+1/x)$ and taking derivatives.

Comment: This problem is from the very beginning of an analysis course, no derivatives have been introduced yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align}
\frac{\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\bigr)^{n+1}}{\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigr)^n}
&= \biggl(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\biggr)^{n+1}\biggl(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\biggr)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{n+1}{n} \\
&= \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\biggr)^{n+1}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n} \\
&> \biggl(1 - \frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2}\biggr)\cdot \frac{n+1}{n} \tag{Bernoulli} \\
&= 1.
\end{align}

Quite similarly (for $n \geqslant  2$, I shift the indices for nicer expressions):

\begin{align}
\frac{\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{n-1}\bigr)^n}{\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigr)^{n+1}}
&= \biggl( 1 + \frac{1}{n-1}\biggr)^n\biggl(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\biggr)^{n+1} \\
&= \biggl(1 + \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n-1)(n+1)}\biggr)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{n-1}{n} \\
&= \biggl(1 + \frac{1}{n^2-1}\biggr)^{n+1} \cdot\frac{n-1}{n} \\
&> \biggl(1 + \frac{n+1}{n^2-1}\biggr)\cdot\frac{n-1}{n} \tag{Bernoulli} \\
&= 1.
\end{align}

Comment: It looks like that the main trick to keep in mind is $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-1}=(1-\frac{1}{n+1})$.